# Schedule a job in android to run at a specific time

Tags: android

I have an Android application which needs to send backup data every midnight to my cloud server. For this I need to schedule the job to occur every 24 hours without fail. I have read about [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) class which can schedule your jobs effectively.

In my case I am using JobScheduler class and here is my **scheduleJob()** method which sets a job to schedule after every 86400000 milliseconds (ie. one day).

```
@RequiresApi(api =Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void scheduleJob(View v){
    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1,new ComponentName(this,JobSchedule.class));
    builder.setPersisted(true);
    builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);
    builder.setPeriodic(86400000);
    builder.setRequiresCharging(false);
    builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(false);
    builder.setBackoffCriteria(10000,JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_EXPONENTIAL);

    int test = jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
    if(test <= 0){
        //sth went wrong
    }

}
```

My question stands is, from where and how should I implement jobSchedule() so that I can get the script to run exactly at 12 midnight.

Also, if I call scheduleJob method from, say, Android's Activity **XYZ**'s onCreate() method, then everytime the Activity **XYZ**  is called, it's override method onCreate() will be called and an additional job will be scheduled. So what should I do and from where should I schedule the job such that only one job is scheduled for the entire lifetime of the application?

To summarize using an example, Whatsapp backs up its data every day at 2 am. Even if I have turned off my net connection, it backs up my data as soon as I come online. I want to implement similar functionality in my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SharedPreference to implement one-time execution. Something like this

```
SharedPreferences wmbPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean isFirstRun = wmbPreference.getBoolean("FIRSTRUN", true);
if (isFirstRun)
{
    // Code to run once
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = wmbPreference.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("FIRSTRUN", false);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: This is the best way I came across to implement one time execution. However, I would like to know the way to execute a task daily at a particular time(in my case 12 midnight).

Comment: you can use setperiodic in the job scheduler but it will not promise accurate time execution because of the battery optimization of android system and the job scheduler will not work for older versions of android.Firebase jobdispatcher is an another option witth that you can use  .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(, )) which will support older versions

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation [JobInfo Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder), setRequieresCharging and setRequieresDeviceIdle are set false by default, so you dont need to set them up false.